# SMP, NUMA, local memory - limits on numer of processors

Tags: memory, computer-architecture

I consider what are limits on number of processor in following models of shared memory:
a. each processor has only own local memory.
b. SMP
c. NUMA

I can't see any limits.  Am I wrong ?

Comment: If you're looking for hard limits, you are correct. Look for soft limits - where adding another CPU doesn't make economic sense, or even slows the app down. Theoretical approach: Model the speed of local accesses, and the (slower) speed of remote accesses(NUMA)  and message passing(SMP). Model the app in terms of how many accesses are local vs remote, and you can model its performance vs cluster size. Practical approach : there's tons of literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When each processor has its own memory, you end up with separate computers in a network. This is limited by the network speed, because you still need to distribute work packages and collect results.

SMP is limited by memory bandwidth. WHen your processor cores compete for memory access, they end up waiting for more and more time, so even if you can add more cores, the total amount of work that can be performed will not rise after some point. In addition, the length of the connection between the cores limits the bus clock.

NUMA is just a specialized network that emulates access to non-local memory, so it still has the same limitations as a regular networked approach, and IIRC the protocol requires direct pairwise connections between cores, so this becomes a signal routing problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is from my answer to [the same question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-SMP-and-NUMA-architectures).

In a Symmetric Multiprocessor, the architectural “distance” to any memory location is the same for all processors, i.e. “symmetric”

In a NonUniform Memory Access machine, each processor is “closer” to some memory locations than others; i.e. memory is partitioned among them Asymmetrically.

Competition for some shared resource is always the limiting factor in terms of how much parallelism (how many processors, say) can be brought to bear on a problem. If you start with an SMP machine with, say, 10 processors, there will be some workloads for which adding an 11th *degrades the performance of each of the first ten* by more than 10% each, and so the overall machine is slower with 11 than 10. (This is why you can buy server CPU’s with a wide range of different core counts.)

Now suppose that for this workload, the memory access pattern could be structured so that each processor is assigned a “workspace”, and that the vast majority of its memory accesses are to its own workspace; it only occasionally needs to read or write data in the workspaces of the others. Further imagine that we architect a machine such that each processor has a private connection to its own workspace, but a shared connection to all the others, i.e. a NonUniform Memory Access machine.

Now, when we add the 11th processor (and 12th, and 13th) total performance goes *up*, not down, since it interferes with the others much less. With enough processors, even that smaller interference will limit total performance, but the limit will be much higher than before.

The benefit of NUMA is that it allows us to bring more processors to bear before mutual competition for memory access destroys the benefit. The disadvantage of NUMA is that it’s more work for the programmer to be aware of memory access patterns, and not every problem can be coded so as to use it well.